# Facebook Request Not Creating Notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am having a strange problem while making app requests. I understand that when an app request is made through my app, it also puts a notification in the top saying so and so has sent a request from this app. Now, while I can successfully make the request, the bookmark count goes up but I do no get a notification at all. Is there something i could be missing? I'm following instructions from this blog post on Facebook developer site - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/. I am new to Facebook development so if it's something simple, please point me in the right direction.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with this in the past but it looks like Facebook have very recently acknowledged this and brought about correcting the issue.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/540/

> **App to User Requests now display messages**
>
> Previously, when apps sent notifications to users (available by posting a request to the apprequests connection of the User Graph object, as documented in Social Channels), the bookmark counters were incremented, but the message included with the notification was not shown. As of this week, if you send an app to user notification, we will also display the notification message in the apps or games dashboards. This provides app developers a more effective way to communicate application-level updates to users. Note that the ticker count is now shown in bookmarks, hovercards and, for games, in the games ticker. As a result of this change, your users may see an increased number of notification messages from your application.

Comment: Does this help answer your question?